# Use Python/pyautogui to control another device

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I'm currently using python's `pyautogui` module to automate typing on my computer. This is a piece of code I currently have:

```
def typeText(prompt):
    pyautogui.typewrite(prompt)
    pyautogui.press('enter')

typeText(prompt='Super secret words :D')
```

Obviously, this will simulate the typing task and type "Super secret words :D" on my computer. But what I want to do now, is to simulate this program on *another* computer I have in my house.

- First off, I don't know if this is even doable using `pyautogui`
  module. If it is, I would like to know how?
- And if it isn't doable, what would be another way to do this without
  the `pyautogui` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is doable in pyautogui but using remote computer control applications like teamviewer and then controlling from there would work.

Comment: And how would I do this with Python code?